# Why does Git have a tea time?

Tags: git

In the [date.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c#L958) file in Git's source code, I note the following structure of special time names:

```
static const struct special {
    const char *name;
    void (*fn)(struct tm *, struct tm *, int *);
} special[] = {
    { "yesterday", date_yesterday },
    { "noon", date_noon },
    { "midnight", date_midnight },
    { "tea", date_tea },
    { "PM", date_pm },
    { "AM", date_am },
    { "never", date_never },
    { "now", date_now },
    { NULL }
};
```

I understand the utility (somewhat) of most of these, but why have a "tea" time (it evaluates to 17:00 hours)? Is this just an [Easter egg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Easter_egg#Noun) of sorts?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This commit might give you a clue as to why it was included:
https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8aca418d6484400d6804e22717bd49ca06c28e9

I think it was suggested initially as a joke, but actually implemented to demonstrate the ability for users to include their own custom time/date periods:

```
On Fri, 18 Nov 2005, David Roundy wrote:
> Don't forget "high noon"!  (and perhaps "tea time"?)  :)


Done.

    [torvalds@g5 git]$ ./test-date "now" "midnight" "high noon" "tea-time"
    now -> bad -> Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969
    now -> Fri Nov 18 08:50:54 2005

    midnight -> bad -> Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969
    midnight -> Fri Nov 18 00:00:00 2005

    high noon -> bad -> Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969
    high noon -> Thu Nov 17 12:00:00 2005

    tea-time -> bad -> Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969
    tea-time -> Thu Nov 17 17:00:00 2005

Thanks for pointing out tea-time.

This is also written to easily extended to allow people to add their own
important dates like Christmas and their own birthdays.

Signed-off-by: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@osdl.org>
Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <junkio@cox.net>
```

Comment: So, to add a new custom date, would one have to recompile Git with their specific changes? Or is there some post-compile step where one can specify these?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with approxidate and how it works to be able to answer.  Judging by the lack of documentation on it, I'd probably say yes - you'd need to recompile git to support it.

Comment: @JonahBishop, didn't you know? You can have custom features if you modify the source and recompile it....

Comment: @PaulDraper Which is even funnier, because the one time I tried to create a small addition to git, it wouldn't even compile right after a clone  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @jhpratt I see no problem here. Nobody promised it'll be easy to use customizations you've added so easily.

Comment: @Atomosk The thing is I would've at least expected git to _compile_ upon cloning the repo. I literally changed nothing.

Comment: @jhpratt Build systems are fun like that, either get used to it or solve the issue and contribute to the free open source project.